# fork() causing non-deterministic behavior: child process doesn't execute

Tags: c, unix, gcc

I have a very simple `c` program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int rc = fork();

    if (rc < 0){
        // fork failed
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        printf("hi, I'm child! %d\n", (int) getpid());
        fflush(stdout);
    } else {
        printf("hi, I'm the parent of %d\n", rc);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, when I compile and run this program, sometimes both print statements will show, but other times only the parent process will show.

Why is this? Even if I don't use `wait()`, both processes should still run.

Using gcc 7.5.0 ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. How are you running the program?

Comment: I'm using the Clion IDE if that makes any difference.

Comment: It should not make a difference. How are you *running* the code? Through the IDE? Try running it inside a terminal and see if anything changes. You are either running an outdated program or experiencing some very strange compiler issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the IDE stops listening when the parent process closes, or the shell leaves the child process stuck in the background.

To see the arbitrary printf order:

```
        int status;
        printf("hi, I'm the parent of %d\n", rc);
        fflush(stdout);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
```